# PHP reports invalid argument for foreach(). Why?

Tags: php

In the following code $stu is declared an array however PHP reports invalid argument for foreach(). Why?

```
echo "<table align='center' border='1px'><tr><td>";
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='POST'>";
$students=array("Jack","John","Ryan");
foreach ($students as $key=>$stu)
 {
echo "Please select a grade for $stu:";
echo "<select name='grade'>";
echo "<option>Grade A</option>";
echo "<option>Grade B</option>";
echo "<option>Grade C</option>";
echo "<option>Grade D</option>";
echo "<option>Grade E</option>";
echo "</select><br/>";
  }
for ($i=0;$i<count($students);$i++)
{
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='stu[]' value='$students[$i]'>";
}

foreach($stu as $arr_contents)
{
echo "$arr_contents";
}

echo "<input type='hidden' name='posted' value='true'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Enter'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</tr></td></table>";
?>
```

Comment: Where is $stu declared as an array? You seem to use it in the first foreach, which is probably what sets it to a non-array.

Comment: If you look at for loop before foreach loop you will see that stu[] is declared an array and on each for loop iteration, $stu is populated with $students contents.

Comment: You do not access `$stu` in the `for` loop so there will be nothing filled in it. What do you want to achieve in the second `foreach` loop?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use $students again in the second loop? Nowhere do you actually define $stu as an array, and pretending otherwise is just confusing us

Answer (score 2):

`$stu` is defined in scope of the first `foreach`, which is closed before it is called in its own `foreach`.  At the end of the first `foreach` loop, it will contain the last used string value, 'Ryan'.

```
// $stu is only known inside this block
foreach ($students as $key=>$stu)
{
}
```

If you want to echo the contents of `$stu` you will have to do it inside the first `foreach` loop.

Comment: $stu will still be defined, and contain the last value from the foreach loop, which'd be 'Ryan'. That's a string, not an array, so the foreach loop OP is complaining about is right... specified argument is not an array.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `$students` is not declared as an associative array with value as an array. It should be something like:

```
$students = array( "Jack" => array( 'array', 'contents' ), "John" => array( 'other', 'content') );
```

Comment: Well, that is what is confusing me, the for loop before foreach, $stu is declared an array and is populated with $students array contents on each loop iteration.

Comment: @dkjain as said in comments to the question, there's no access to `$stu` in the `for` loop. Are you sure you reported the whole code?